# Which is better on a laptop - R5 2400U with GTX1050 4GB, or i5 8265U with MX150 2GB?

Tags: laptop, graphics-cards, processor

Can you guys please suggest which one of these LAPTOPS will be better and why? All of these have 8GB of RAM.

1. Ryzen 5 2400U processor, GTX1050 4GB Graphics
2. i5-8250U processor, Radeon 530 4GB Graphics
3. i5-8265U processor, MX150 2GB Graphics
4. i5-8250U processor, MX130 2GB Graphics

I think all of these processors are similar, am I correct?
But I'm not so sure if graphics memory is more important, or graphics chipset?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The ranking of those GPUs fastest to slowest is: GTX 1050, MX 150, MX 130, Radeon 530. The GPU chipset is usually much more important than the amount of VRAM for performance. I will have to research those CPUs before posting a full answer though.

Comment: So you are saying that, it is better to go with MX150/MX130 2GB instead of Radeon 530 4GB ? Also, what are your findings regarding the CPUs? Thanks for replying.

Comment: The Ryzen 5 2400U seems to be marginally weaker than the Intel i5's. However, the GTX1050 is *significanty* better than the 530 and MX150 graphics cards - it's not even close.
I never understood the point of those incredibly low-performance graphics cards to begin with - even modern Ryzen iGPUs are far more powerful than them.

Comment: Agreed, the GTX 1050 is the only one that is worth your money as a standalone GPU. The MX150 isn't even fast enough to reach 60fps at 1366x768 (a typical low-end laptop resolution) for many games, which makes it sit an an awkward spot in laptop GPU performance. It's too slow for gaming (except for older games) and overkill for HD video & multimedia.

Answer (score 1):

**I would suggest you to go for 1. Ryzen 5 2400U processor & GTX1050 4GB Graphics**

=> `GTX1050` is the best GPU among all of them.

=> `AMD Ryzen 5 2400U` and ``Intel Core i5 8250U` performs very close.